# "Nine crazy years at the ticker"?

Tags: vocabulary

From Franklin Delano Roosevelt's [1936 Madison Square Garden speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1936_Madison_Square_Garden_speech):

> "For twelve years this Nation was afflicted with hear-nothing,
>   see-nothing, do-nothing Government. The Nation looked to Government
>   but the Government looked away. Nine mocking years with the golden
>   calf and three long years of the scourge! Nine crazy years at the
>   **ticker** and three long years in the breadlines!"

What does [ticker](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ticker) mean in this context? Is it a [stock ticker](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stock_ticker)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this indeed means the stock ticker.

Remember that Roosevelt gave this speech in the context of his 1936 re-election bid, three days before Election Day. He was reminding everyone about what had happened during the 12 years (3+9=12) of Republican control (1921-1933) before he was elected the first time.

In Roosevelt's reasoning, something happened 9 years into that period to cause the 3 years of bread lines. That thing was the stock market crash of October 29, 1929.

Roosevelt's rhetoric here is a kind of [synecdoche](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/synecdoche), where a part of something (standing at the stock ticker) is made to stand in for the whole (the obssession with getting rich quick, with little regard for the future). The stock ticker helped enable this obsession. The obssession was "crazy" because the stock market is a poor indicator of the overall health of the economy -- the [Gordon Gekko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordon_Gekko)s of the world outnumbered the Lou Mannheims, even then.